# Error when using Control_Surface: usb_midi_handleSysExPartial cast error

Tags: controls, usb, midi, surface, teensy

When trying to compile the following code in Arduino IDE using the Control_Surface MIDI library, I stumble upon a cast error coming from `usb_midi_handleSysExPartial` function in the `usb_midi.h` library.

```
#include <Control_Surface.h>

USBMIDI_Interface midi;

CCPotentiometer potentiometer {
  A0,
  {MIDI_CC::Channel_Volume, Channel_1},
};

void setup() {
  Control_Surface.begin();
}

void loop() {
  Control_Surface.loop();
}
```

The log is quite extensive, so I've dropped it into pastebin to avoid flooding this thread:
https://pastebin.com/LSKuWh1x

I've tried compiling on 2 different devices, checking I've got the newest versions of Teensyduino (1.58.1), MIDIUSB (1.0.5) and Control_Surface libraries.